# Plot Dbscan cluster of lidar data in new window in r

Tags: r, lidar

have used DBSCAN to cluster my data and would like to plot the results in a new window using R. Currently, the results are plotted in the RStudio plot window which is not big enough to see the result. How can I plot the results in a new window?

Here is the code I have used to perform the clustering and generate the plot:

```
x <- lasPlanar$X
y <- lasPlanar$Y
z <- lasPlanar$Z
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)

dbscan_result <- dbscan(df, eps = 1, minPts = 10)

cluster_table <- table(dbscan_result$cluster)

plot_ly(x = x, y = y, z = z, type = "scatter3d", mode = "markers",
        marker = list(color = dbscan_result$cluster),
        colors = c("#000000", "#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF",
                   "#FFFF00", "#FF00FF", "#00FFFF", "#C0C0C0"),
        hoverinfo = "text")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the Zoom button in the viewer to get a bigger window.  I don't know if there's a way to do that in code, but you can get things to display in your default browser instead of the viewer by running

```
options(viewer = function(..., height) utils::browseURL(...))
```

first.  (The reason you need that funny call is that RStudio's viewer may pass a `height` argument, but `browseURL()` doesn't accept that.)